# How to set default controller for an area

Tags: custom-route

I'm creating utility pages and the structure of the code files is as below:

```
/Areas/MyTools/Controllers/UpdateField  
/Areas/MyTools/Views/UpdateField/Index.cshtml
```

When I browse http://mysite/mytools/updatefield, it works fine and I would like to open the same page for http://mysite/mytools/ as well.

Is it done differently in Sitecore?

**SOLUTION:**

@Hishaam's answer fixed it. Here is all the code for anyone experiencing the same issue.

**MinionsAreaRegistration.cs**

This class is created in the project, when you add an area. Add a new route in `RegisterArea`

```
public class MinionsAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "MyTools";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "MyTools_default",
                "MyTools/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            context.MapRoute(
                "MyTools_Home",
                "MyTools/{id}",
                new { controller = "UpdateField", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }                 
            );
        }
    }
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

This class is also created when you add a MVC project. Add a new map route in `RegisterRoutes`.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "MyTools_Home",
                "MyTools/{id}",
                new { controller = "UpdateField", action = "Index", area = "MyTools", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "MyTools_default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Try to add a new Route as follows: `routes.MapRoute(
 "MyTools", // Route name
 "MyTools/{id}", // URL with parameters 
 new { controller = "UpdateField", action = "Index", area = "MyTools", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);    `

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I tried keeping the new route above & also below the default in code. Neither worked :( It still redirects to requested document not found page

Comment: Did you try the one in my comment? Place it above the default route

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Yes, tried your code and updated the same in question. Please take a look

Comment: From the one I've shared, can you please add the namespace also. Example: ` routes.MapRoute(  "MyTools",  "mytools/{id}",  new { controller = "UpdateField", action = "Index", area = "MyTools", id = UrlParameter.Optional },  new[] { "Namespace.Controllers" });`

Comment: No luck with the namespace too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register the Area. So, create a registration area under the path `/Areas/MyTools/`. You can name it `MyToolRegistrationArea.cs`.

In the `MyToolRegistrationArea.cs`, add the following

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public class MyToolRegistrationArea : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "MyTool";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            var myToolRoute = context.MapRoute(
                "MyTool",
                "mytool",
                new { controller = "UpdateField", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "YourNamespace.Controllers" });

            myToolRoute.RouteHandler = new Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHandlerWrapper(myToolRoute.RouteHandler);
        }
    }
}
```